# HTML: All XML data values show up unformatted below formated document

Tags: html, xml, xslt-1.0

Very newbie here (less than week).

I have a stylesheet created from Altova StyleVision that I have modified as it didn't work in a browser outside of StyleVision. Something about "The variable or parameter 'altova:table' was duplicated within the same scope."

Anyway, it works beautifully now, except for one thing. At the end of the formatted view, all the XML data values are repeated again unformatted, just spewed out in one continuous line.

I have searched and searched for an answer before posting here, but no one seems to have encountered this before.

The code is all inside an HTML  tag and looks like this:

```
  <BODY>
    <span style="font-family:Arial; font-size:18pt; font-weight:bold; vertical-align:middle; ">
      <xsl:text>ENGINEERING CHANGE ORDER</xsl:text>
    </span>
     .............
      <br/>
      <span style="font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-weight:bold; ">
        <xsl:text>Summary:</xsl:text>
      </span>
      <pre>
        <xsl:for-each select="Description">
          <span style="font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; ">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
          </span>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </pre>
      <hr/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </BODY>
```

Comment: This looks like XSLT. It should be fed through an XSLT processor.

Comment: You've created 'a monster'. It's neither pure HTML, nor XSLT anymore. Every thing with 'xsl:' in it is XSLT and won't be 'processed' by a browser.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what you're trying to achieve here. Recreating your problem, I was thinking you are referring to the output being one continuous string?

If so, you are using namespace and attributes that wouldn't exist on an HTML document. One method that is more common is creating the actual stylesheet. An Sample.xsl file. Keeping to a relative same format you provided. Here is an XSL file that you can parse with an DATA.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xml:lang="en" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"  />
            <title>
            <xsl:value-of select="'Altova StyleVision'"/>
            </title>
        </head>
        <BODY>
            <span style="font-family:Arial; font-size:18pt; font-weight:bold; vertical-align:middle; ">
                <xsl:text>ENGINEERING CHANGE ORDER</xsl:text>
            </span>
            .............
            <br/>
            <span style="font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; font-weight:bold; ">
                <xsl:text>Summary:</xsl:text>
            </span>
            <pre>
                <span style="font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; ">
                    <xsl:for-each select="document('DATA.xml')/profile/description">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="value"/>
                        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
                                <![CDATA[<br />]]>
                            </xsl:text>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </span>
            </pre>
            <hr/>
        </BODY>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

My sample DATA.xml contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<profile>
    <description>
        <value>hi</value>
    </description>
    <description>
        <value>world</value>
    </description>
    <description>
        <value>i mean</value>
    </description>
    <description>
        <value>hello</value>
    </description>
    <description>
        <value>world</value>
    </description>
</profile>
```

If you are using a Mac or Linux based operating system. You can open terminal and type
`xsltproc sample.xsl DATA.xml > index.html` Now that will parse a HTML file for you to view as HTML. If you are using a Windows machine, go here: http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/xsltproc2.html and download a copy of xsltproc so you can parse that content.

If you have a copy of the example.xml that you created, and want to display the data using XSL. This is a great way to go about it. Especially when you have a lot of content on the XML file.

Comment: I see that I have lots and lots to learn. What has me especially confused is that I'm basically being told this shouldn't work as is, and yet the XML data values are being nicely displayed in Internet Explorer and Firefox. It's only that the xml data values get repeated with no stylesheet formatting at the end of the document. Tyler, you have given the most detailed info, thanks. What I need to do is step back towards the beginning and learn more about XSLT and HTML and parsers, etc. I was hoping to shortcut a solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no shortcut solution to much things in life. If you are having your XML data values repeated, it's most likely a loop done wrong; <xsl:apply-templates select="example"> and <xsl:for-each select="example">. Both apply-templates and for-each are basically loops. Your nested loop, that's probably what's creating the repeated values. Fiddle with the code, the only way to learn it is actually playing with it, I code in XML/XSL for a living, but there's still much to learn for me. You can add more to this post if you need a little help. Always happy to help.

Comment: By the way, XML data will almost always display nicely because it's just raw data. Your XSL is what makes it "stylish". Think of XML as just data. XSL as styling like HTML & CSS combined and XSLT as transformation of XML AND XSL into whatever format you desire. Great beginning start is from W3Schools. More in depth would require a book or just looking online for how others code. If you have the option to get some XML and XSL code, fiddling with it will help the learning process. It's actually a fairly simple styling language compared to many others. Great addition to the resume, Thumbs Up!